# Error handling in the repository (API REST)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this situation (method in Repository):

```
public string Get(string name)
{
    string response;

    try
    {
        using (var context = new MyDB())
        {
            var row = context.TblSomething.FirstOrDefault();
            response = row.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(row, null).ToString();
        }

        return response;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

When there is content other than the Property in the name field, it throws an exception

The method is called in the `Controller`

```
public IActionResult Get(string name)
{
    string response;

    try
    {
        response = _module.MyRepository().Get(name);
    }
    catch (ValidationException e)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { error = new { message = e.Message, value = e.Value } });
    }

    return Ok(response);
}
```

How to make it not return a 500 error to the user but should be BadRequest?

Answer (score 4):

The way to make it return 400 instead of 500 is to *actually* catch the exception. You already have a catch block that returns `BadRequest`, so the only assumption that can be made is that `ValidationException` is not what's being thrown. Catch the *actual* exception being thrown and you're good.

That said, absolute do not catch an exception merely to throw the same exception. All you're doing is slowing down your app. You should also *never* catch `Exception`, unless you're simply trying to generally log all exceptions and then rethrow. If you don't have a specific handler for an exception type, then don't catch it. In other words, remove these lines:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
    throw e;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

If you're not going to handle *any* exceptions as your repo code does, then don't use a try block at all.

It's also worth mentioning that you shouldn't rely on exceptions unless you have to. Throwing exceptions is a drain on performance. In a situation like this, you should simply return `null`, instead of throwing an exception when there's no matching property. Then, you can do a null check to verify instead of a try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own [Exception Handling Middleware](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/) to catch 500 error and return your custom error status code and message.

1.Create the middleware:

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context )
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {

        HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        string message = "Something is wrong!";


        httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; // Or whatever status code you want to return
        message = exception.Message; // Or whatever message you want to return


        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            error = message,

        });

        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

2.Add it into the middleware pipeline after `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{                
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ExceptionHandlingMiddleware));
}
```